# Class D amplifier safety

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, switching, powermosfet, class-d

This is my first time I had success in doing a class D amplifier. Earlier attempts was on prototype boards with bad layouts. This time I made a good layout considering parasitics and it works good even without snubber. It's impressive how efficient is, I get loud music with 4 mA average current.

Problem is my FETs are 40 V ones and I want to use up to 3/4 of that voltage. I calculated a snubber 3.9 Ω + 750 pF, but it suppresses only ringing without the spike enough for the goal.

I'm new to this, to RF realm, what am I missing? My first impedance matching was making a VGA to scope XYZ converter. I'm interested in the safety here, FETs are expensive here where I live, and I have spend much money on this.

Can you tell me what safety procedures to follow? Thanks :)

[image: layout]

Added schematic
[image: schem]

Edit: I missed to draw the connection between SW node and NCP3420.

Edit2: I forgot to mention, I calculated for the snubber a 5 Ohm resistor and scaled that to 0.75 for 3.9 Ω. Fring is 34.45 MHz, ftest with 1.14 n is around 18, calculated for a damping factor of 1, supply voltage must be at least 24 V and switching frequency is 100 kHz. Only thing I didn't calculate is Cboot, I think used 680 nF. I watch DS of lower side.

Comment: Schematic please and, pin-point where you think a snubber is needed. Please also supply links to main component data sheets. Amend your question with this information please. Don't put the links in comments.

Comment: @Andyaka added it, forgot to mention, i calculated 1n for snubber with 5 ohm resistor and scaled that to 0.75 for 3.9ohm. Fring is 34.45 mhz, ftest with 1.14n is around 18, calculated for damping factor 1, supply voltage must be at least 24V, sw freq is 100khz. Only thing i not calculated is Cboot, i think used 680n

Comment: Please don't roll back the edit revision when you add things to your question.

Comment: I didnt, maybe edit happened during edition and when posted, it rolled back